# Fullcalendar con eventos extraídos de una BD

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

Tengo la intención de implementar fullcalendar en un proyecto que estoy realizando para la universidad, se visualiza correctamente, más sin embargo no logro mostrar eventos extraídos de mi base de datos, aquí anexo lo que llevo...

Este es mi `HTML`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Peticiones de Servicios</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.css">
    <link href='css/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/calendario.css">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- fullcalendar -->
    <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/locale/es.js"></script>
    <script src="js/calendario.js"></script>
    <!-- image-picker -->
    <script src="js/image-picker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/image-picker.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Este es el archivo `PHP` donde almaceno las consultas del proyecto... `consultas.php`

```html
<?php 
 class Consultas
 {        
        public function cargarEventosPorMesAPartirDeFechaActual(){
            $fecha;
            $fecha = date('Y-m-d');            
            
            $modelo = new Conexion();
            $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
            $sql = "SELECT tipoServicio, inicioSolicitud, finSolicitud, estadoServicio, idUsuario
                    FROM servicios
                    INNER JOIN peticiones ON servicios.idPeticion = peticiones.idPeticion
                    WHERE CAST(peticiones.inicioSolicitud AS DATE) >= $fecha
                    AND peticiones.finSolicitud < DATE_ADD( '$fecha', INTERVAL 1 MONTH)";
   $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
   $statement->execute();   
   return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    }
?>
```

Y este archivo `PHP` es a donde realizo la petición `AJAX`.... `cargarEventos.php`

```html
<?php

 require_once('../Modelo/class.conexion.php');
 require_once('../Modelo/class.consultas.php');

 $consultas = new Consultas();
 $datos = $consultas->cargarEventosPorMesAPartirDeFechaActual();

 $results = (count($datos) > 0) ? $datos : array("error"=>"No hay opciones en la BD");
 $arrayJson = json_encode($results);
 print_r($arrayJson);

?>
```

Como ya tengo registros que realicé manualmente, cuando corro en mi servidor local `http://localhost/RespaldoRecuperacion/Controlador/cargarEventos.php`
obtengo en pantalla los registros con formato `JSON`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi archivo `JS` en donde realizó la peticion `AJAX`, aquí también inicio el calendario y apunto al `Div` que lo contendrá.

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Declaramos el arreglo que contendra los eventos
    var eventosBD = new Array();
    
    var tipoServicio, inicioSolicitud, finSolicitud, estadoServicio, idUsuario, nombreClase;
    
    $.get('Controlador/cargarEventos.php', function(data) {         
     $.each(data, function(idx, opt) {                  
            idUsuario = (data[idx].idUsuario);            
            tipoServicio = (data[idx].tipoServicio);            
            inicioSolicitud = (data[idx].inicioSolicitud);            
            finSolicitud = (data[idx].finSolicitud);            
            estadoServicio = (data[idx].estadoServicio);            
            
            if(estadoServicio == 1){
              nombreClase = 'tareas-realizadas';
            }            
            eventosBD =    
                [
                    {
                        title: tipoServicio,
                        start: inicioSolicitud,
                        end: finSolicitud,
                        className: nombreClase
        }
                ]            
            console.log(eventosBD);
     });
 }, 'json');

    var date = new Date();
    
    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    var initialLocaleCode = 'es';
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
        },
        defaultView: 'month',
        defaultDate: date,
        locale: initialLocaleCode,
        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
        //CODIGO QUE NO TIENE NADA QUE VER EN ESTA PREGUNTA
          },
        events: eventosBD
    })

});
```

En ese `console.log(eventosBD);` en mi archivo `JS` me regresa esto en la consola..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Más sin embargo en el calendario no se ve reflejado ningún evento que he extraído, ¿alguna recomendación?, desde ya, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para la persona interesada....

Cambié mi `cargarEventos.php` y trate lo que me arrojaba el `cargarEventosPorMesAPartirDeFechaActual()`

Quedando de la siguiente manera....

```html
<?php

 require_once('../Modelo/class.conexion.php');
 require_once('../Modelo/class.consultas.php');

 $consultas = new Consultas();
 $datos = $consultas->cargarEventosPorMesAPartirDeFechaActual();

    $eventos = array();    

    foreach($datos as $resultado){
        $title = $resultado['tipoServicio'];
        $start = $resultado['inicioSolicitud'];
        $end = $resultado['finSolicitud'];
        $id = $resultado['idUsuario'];
        $clase = $resultado['estadoServicio'];
        if($clase=='1'){
            $clase = "tareas-realizadas";
        }elseif($clase == '2'){
            $clase = "tareas-programadas-vigentes";
        }elseif($clase == '3'){
            $clase = "tareas-programadas-vencidas";
        }else{
            $clase = "peticion-sin-asignar";
        }
        
        $eventos[] = array('id' => $id, 'title' => $title, 'start' => $start, 'end' => $end, 'className' => $clase);
    }
        
    $arrayJson = json_encode($eventos, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    print_r($arrayJson); 
?>
```

Y mi archivo `js` donde cargo mi calendario y sus eventos de la siguiente manera...

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
  
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
    var initialLocaleCode = 'es';
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
        },
        events: {
        url: 'Controlador/cargarEventos.php',
        cache: true
    },
        defaultView: 'month',
        defaultDate: date,
        locale: initialLocaleCode,
        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            //CODIGO SIN IMPORTANCIA
        }        
    })

});
```

De esa manera ya puedo visualizar en mi calendario los eventos que extraigo de mi base de datos...

¡Saludos y éxito!

Comment: me ha servido mucho tu caso! Gracias por postear la solución.

Comment: De nada, me alegro que te sirva la solucion que propuse en el post, saludos!